# How to prevent textview in toolbar from pushing out icons?

Tags: android, xml

I have a toolbar which contains a textview and 2 images which are aligned on the left. As the textview grows in size, it starts to push the images off the screen. I know to prevent this you can use a relative layout inside the toolbar and set the textview to left of the images or use a linear layout but for some reason when I do this the textview gets pushed up a little. Is there a fix to this problem? Thanks

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="#4d4a4a4a"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editButton"
                android:lines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLength="30"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/download"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vertical_align_bottom_white_18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/download"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: Use maxwidth attribute in xml

Comment: It has to work on different sizes though, so it can't be one number.

Comment: code please, you have 181 reputation and still don't know how to ask question's here.

Comment: Can you attach some images? For example of how your `TextView` gets pushed "a little" when you use an inner layout?

Comment: Sorry for that. I added code and an image.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Here's the code for anyone else who has this problem!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="#4d4a4a4a"
        android:elevation="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editButton">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:lines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/download"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_vertical_align_bottom_white_18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/editButton"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/download"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```